# html/javascript: ID of a button is changing (?)

Tags: javascript, php, html

On my webpage I have 2 buttons and both of them should return a different 'confirm' popup depending on what button has been pressed.

The code:

```
<form action = "markascomplete.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return validateForm();">

echo '<tr><td><button id = "btnComplete" style = "submit" class = "btn btn-success" name = "btnComplete" value = "btnComplete">Voltooi deze taak</button></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><button id = "btnDeComplete" style = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger" name = "btnDeComplete" value = "btnDeComplete">Markeren als onvoltooid</button></td></tr>';

function validateForm()
{
    var btnMark = document.getElementById( 'btnMark' );
    var btnActive = document.getElementById( 'btnActive' );
    var btnComplete = document.getElementById( 'btnComplete' );
    var btnDeComplete = document.getElementById( 'btnDeComplete' );

    alert( btnDeComplete.value );

    var sConfirmText = "";
    var sAlertText = "";

    if( btnMark )
    {
        //alert( btnMark.value );
        sConfirmText = "Test1";
        sAlertText = "Test2";
    }
    else if( btnActive )
    {
        //alert( btnActive.value );
        sConfirmText = "Test3";
        sAlertText = "Test4";
    }
    else if( btnComplete )
    {
        alert( btnComplete.value );
        alert( 'btncomplete' );
        sConfirmText = "Test5";
        sAlertText = "Test6";
    }
    else if( btnDeComplete )
    {
        alert( btnDeComplete.value );
        alert( 'btndecomplete' );
        sConfirmText = "Test7";
        sAlertText = "Test8";
    }

    if( confirm( sConfirmText ) )
    {
        alert( sAlertText );
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

So what should happen when you press any of those buttons, it should give you an alert with the value of btnDeComplete, show two alerts with 'Test' + the given number of the button that has been pressed.

Now when you press the button btnComplete, you get the following alerts:
btnComplete
btncomplete
Test5
Test6

When you press the button btnDeComplete, you get the following alerts: 
btnComplete
btncomplete
Test5
Test6

Notice that they're both the same, and the first 'alert( btnDeComplete.value );' returns btnComplete instead of btnDeComplete. 
I'm not changing any of the ID's or values anywhere in the code, I just set the id, name and value where I create the buttons.

All of the other buttons work just fine.

Anyone could help me with this problem?

Comment: just add a html5 data-* property to your button, fetch it on click and based on that you can differentiate.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao This way all the buttons can have the same id, and I can just change the data-* value to whatever I need, right?
Edit: And is it possible to call the data-* value in PHP?

Comment: Its a very bad idea to have a single id for different controls and its not suggested. So what I say is keep a single class or add one more common class for all the buttons and on click of that class fetch the data-* attribute and based on that manipulate however you need. Edit : Are you using jQuery by any means? If yes, I can give you a better answer to this. But am not sure how you do this in php

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes I am using jQuery aswell, I'm gonna try to do it like you suggested but please post that jQuery solution aswell. Always good to learn new things :)

Comment: Sure. I will post the solution.. :) Edit: By the way am not finding where you are ending your form and what other controls form contains. I will just post a general solution to load particular text on modal on click of particular button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just elaborate with a general scenario

```
<form action = "markascomplete.php" id="frmMarks" method = "post">

echo '<tr><td><button id = "btnComplete" style = "submit" class = "btn btn-success btnClick" name = "btnComplete" data-option="Success" value = "btnComplete">Voltooi deze taak</button></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><button id = "btnDeComplete" style = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger btnClick" name = "btnDeComplete" data-option="Delete" value = "btnDeComplete">Markeren als onvoltooid</button></td></tr>';

</form>
```

**EDIT :**

```
    <script>
     $('.btnClick').on('click',function(){
    var sConfirmText = "";
    var sAlertText = "";
    var sDataOption = $(this).attr("data-option");

if( sDataOption == "btnMark" )
{
    alert( 1 );
    sConfirmText = "1";
    sAlertText = "1";
}
else if( sDataOption == "btnActive" )
{
    alert( 2 );
    sConfirmText = "2";
    sAlertText = "2";
}
else if( sDataOption == "btnComplete" )
{
    alert( 3 );
    sConfirmText = "3";
    sAlertText = "3";
}
else 
{
    alert( 4 );
    sConfirmText = "4";
    sAlertText = "4";
}

if( confirm( sConfirmText ) )
{
    alert( sAlertText );
    $('#frmMarks').submit();
}
else
    return false;
});
    </script>
```

**Edit**

As per what I have seen from your paste bin link you have missed one more `=` sign in `else if` statement and I would like to convert your last `else if` statement to just an  `else` statement as I have shown in my edit. Just check if this works. Also a suggestion, you can use `switch` case instead of `if else` which is better in performance when you have multiple check to be done.

Comment: I've tried this code, but I'm still having the same problem as before, except now it's calling 'btnActive' all the time. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XgK9GEqC)
Edit: The jQuery part is in a <script> block

Comment: I dont understand.. Where is btnActive here?? Please give me a complete scenario!!

Comment: See the pastebin link

Comment: Wow, I feel so embarrassed now that i've seen what I did wrong. This was indeed the problem, thank you for helping out! Also, with how many if statements is a switch statement better to use?

Comment: These small mistakes happens with every programmer which will be very difficult to identify.. :) What I feel is, if you have 2 or more than that else ifs you can go for switch statement which checks the case and directly goes to that particular statement to execute. Whereas in if-else it will check each and every condition which is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running a series of if conditions, it's running the code in the first one that matches true. It's not executing the code in the first couple of if conditions, because those elements don't exist hence btnActive and btnComplete variables are null or false, so the if condition fails and the code for those isn't executed.

The top of your javascript is simply using getElement to assign those elements (if they exist in the document) to variables, and it won't make a difference which button is pressed as they both call the same function.

Within the function you could use this.id to get the id of the button that is pressed.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If I want to use this.id, I need to assign the button(s) in the function as a parameter right? Because I tried using this.id but it returned me 'undefined'